# Check if a word exists in an excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I made a survey (lots of rows) with text as output. I want to be able o find The most important information for each variable. The variable here would be the country (I have about 20) and the key words would be a list that I have created (price, quality, delivery etc.) I want to be able to understand how many times the word "delivery" occured from a specific panel (country). And I need to do that for all of them. I think of a countif + vlookup formula but can't manage to find how.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: What happened to the sample table in the question? There are several answers based on the input sample

Comment: You have changed your question so much that I have deleted my answer. Please edit your question to include **as text which can be copy/pasted** a representative data sample, along with what you have tried to solve your problem, and what you expect for a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using in this way perhaps:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D3`

```
=LET(x,$B$3:$B$5,SUM(LEN(PROPER(x))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(x),PROPER(C3),)))/LEN(C3))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=SUM(DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,$B$3:$B$5,
LAMBDA(a,b,N(VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,{" ",".","?",","})=C3)))),""),1))
```

---

Just so we avoid `TEXTJOIN()` and it's limits.

---

**Edit:**

Not aware of your **Excel Version**, here is an alternative.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F3`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(PROPER($B$3:$B$5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER($B$3:$B$5),PROPER(C3),)))/LEN(C3)
```

---

Comment: Just a comment about the `TEXTJOIN` limit. I realized the limit is in the number of text arguments, but you can have more than 252 cells, in a single argument (which is the case of the question). For example the following works: `=TEXTJOIN(",",,SEQUENCE(260))`, since it is using just one text argument, this is my understanding.

Comment: I am doubtful about it, because when I gave the solution, I was trying Ron Sir's solution with the same series of sentences for 2K data where it was giving me `#CALC!` error. I have not tried yours Sir yet. But it hurts more that, OP keeps changing their question when solutions were already posted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and I apologize for not being able to express my need moe clearly. I have 1 column with entries (4000 unique rows with text) and 1 column with countries (20 unique countries). As I can't go through each feedback, I have made a list of key words (materialized with 20 columns) . I'd like to have my 20 countries in rows, the 20 key words in column and find how many times they appeared for each country. I tried countif + vlookup (in the wrong way for sure) and I'd need the formula as I'm completely stuck! Thanks again for your help

Comment: @mdc123 in situations like this, what is recommended it to keep the original question as it was, specially if other answers were provided, and create a new question, specially if any update to the question changes the question's scope. The answers we provide here are not just for you, but the community too. Now with your updated question, it is not clear what are the answer responding to.

Comment: @DavidLeal Sir, agree, with you snatch the words from my mouth. I dont want to hurt by saying this to mdc123, experts and members with limited knowledge like me have already invested their time, they wont like to change it, if there were minor changes then it was fine to deliver but here may or may need to deliver new formula. there is no issue if you create a new post. This community `StackOverflow` is the best i have seen so far and like to learn from here more. Very helpful and organized!!!

Comment: @DavidLeal Sir, how can I share a copy with you, will it be ok if i share a one drive link here. So you can check once. I tried yours as well. Sorry to say I faced the same challenge.

Comment: I will test my solution for a larger dataset, but if there is an issue it should not be `TEXTJOIN` as per my example in the comment using `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: @DavidLeal Sir, kindly try on this it is in edit mode, [Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cimj6q7K4x3rm8a7L?e=AqhVch)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I tested it, and it works up to row 2093, which is weird, because as per [TEXTJOIN documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) the limit is 252 text input arguments, not this number, I guess it reached another Excel limit, not documented in the function, related to the maximum number of characters can fit into a cell. Interesting. I tested it up to 300 rows and it works, actually the limit was way much bigger for this case. Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidLeal Sir, actually the limit is per cell i.e. as per documentation `If the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), TEXTJOIN returns the #VALUE! error` So when you are concatenating ranges of around 2093 eventually the limit exceeds for sentences show as in example, it may be less rows based on the strings length you concatenate. if you make the sentence example much larger, i believe it will certainly reduce no of rows working as well.

Comment: @DavidLeal Sir, also I wont take credit of all this knowledge, I learnt it from [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) Sir. Amazing Teacher, explains so nice and neat!

Answer (score 2):

The following spills the entire result for all words:

```
=LET(words, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ",, A2:A4),,{" ","?"},1), ux, UNIQUE(words),
 cnts, BYROW(ux, LAMBDA(x, ROWS(FILTER(words, words=x)))), HSTACK(ux, cnts))
```

### Update

The previous solution uses `TEXTJOIN` which join the entire input in a single cell. As it was discussed in the comments section of @MayukhBhattacharya's answer, for a large data set it can reach the cell size limit. To avoid it will end up in a similar solution he already provided. Kudos to Mayukh!. The main difference is that the following spills the entire result all at once:

```
=LET(A, A2:A4, words, DROP(REDUCE("", A, LAMBDA(ac,x,
 VSTACK(ac, TEXTSPLIT(x,,{" ","?"},1)))),1), ux, UNIQUE(words), 
 cnts, BYROW(ux, LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(words=x)))), HSTACK(ux, cnts))
```

**Notes**:

1. In `TEXTSPLIT` you can define additional word delimiters, such punctuation signs, etc.
2. Instead of `FILTER` and `ROWS` you can use: `SUM(N(words=x))`

[image: excel output]

Just for fun, you can encapsulate the previous calculation in a user `LAMBDA` function as follows and then call it for specific string, in case the word was not found, it returns: `Not found`:

```
=LET(Z, LAMBDA(x,y, LET(words, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ",, x),,{" ","?"},1),
 ux, UNIQUE(words), cnts, BYROW(ux, LAMBDA(x, ROWS(FILTER(words, words=x)))),
 FILTER(cnts, ux=y, "Not Found"))), Z(A2:A4,"dog"))
```

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION:
Let's say I had the following:

```
   A       B   C
   -       -   -
1  COW
2  PIG
3  CHICKEN
4  COW
5              =COUNTIF($A1:$A4,"COW")
```

C5 would show "2".

To split text (e.g. "To be or not to be") you could use string functions like [LEFT(), RIGHT() and MID()](https://spreadsheeto.com/text-functions/)